# Hide element, but keep it clickable?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button generated inside an iframe. Unfortunately, I can't change how it looks, as it's delivered by 3rd party library. I thought of a little trick to use my own button and keep the generated one inside:

```
<button id="my-button">Click Me</button>
```

This way, I can tell the library to place its buttons inside mine, so the `<iframe>` would get appended like this:

```html
<button id="my-button">
    Click Me
    <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</button>
```

Now, the only thing left is to hide the `<iframe>`. I can't simply use `visibility: hidden`, because that way the `click` event no longer works. Why I did is instead:

```css
#my-button {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#my-button > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .0001;
}
```

It seems to be a good solution, as I don't see the 3rd party button and I can do whatever I want with my own button. I just need to make sure it's not larger that the button inside, which would render part of my own button unclickable.

What I would prefer, would be rendering that other element somewhere else and hiding it with `display: none` or `position: absolute` outside of my viewport and then triggering the click inside it. Due to modern CORS policies, as far as I know it's not possible to reach elements inside the `<iframe>` though - am I right?

Is there any more reliable way to achieve the same effect without so much trickery? I'm not that excited about `opacity: .0001`, it make me anxious that in some browsers it will leave some visible trace of the other button.

Comment: try display:none css property

Comment: _“It seems to be a good solution”_ - it’s invalid HTML (`button` must not contain other _interactive_ elements, and `iframe` is one of those), so it would be heavily dependent on what exactly a browser’s error correction makes out of this in the first place. And rather than being anxious about that it might leave some visible trace, I’d be concerned about this getting detected as an attempt a click-jacking …

Comment: @misorude if one wants, he or she will trick people to click anything. It's the intent that makes the practice a violation or not. I just want to tweak the appearance of the button to match my app, that's all.

Comment: Yes, but systems developed to fight click-jacking are going to look for suspicious behavior / actions, they are not very likely to bother to determine your actual intent. Not saying that necessarily applies here, we don’t know what kind of widget you are embedding there and what it does … Just saying stuff like this should be kept in mind, before considering something like this as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It isn’t possible to have an element of the parent trigger a click on a button (or any other element) within an iFrame for security reasons.

Comment: It is very possible, but not in a cross-domain case (unless you've control over both the domains).

Comment: @Teemu True, but I guess the person asking the question would have changed the css in the iFrame instead of trying the above.